# Deleted Partitions and Wasted Storage

Tags: disk-utility, partition, storage, diskutil, disk-volume

After doing `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            140.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

and `sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2          4         Pri GPT table
        6      76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    76806   34169245      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 34246051     158692      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 34404743   87733384
122138127          4         Sec GPT table
122138131          1         Sec GPT header
```

I deleted some partitions I was using for a dual boot with Ubuntu using gdisk, but now Disk Utility nor diskutil will show empty space from deleting the volumes. Although my GUID_partition_scheme shows I have 500 gigs on the disk, the space is just gone and no longer able to be expanded to the "Macintosh HD" partition. I tried rebooting but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3439894 It says, "No CoreStorage logical volume groups found" and Disk Utility wouldn't let me delete them, so its not like I had any other choice.

Comment: @Midi, Did you try using `diskutil` from Terminal vs the Disk Utility app to remove what you deleted with `gdisk` before resorting to it?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I tried both.

Comment: @klanomath So any ideas?

Comment: @klanomath If you add it to the answers, then I'll select it if you want. Thanks.

Comment: @klanomath indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under these circumstances - only one main volume - the proper command to expand it to its full size is:

```
diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 R
```

This command will not work if your main volume is part of a CoreStorage Volume Group.